# scrape html page and return all strings where len is greater than 8

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a page where I want to return all strings found. I am using python

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

doc = "https://www.kite.com/"
res = requests.get(doc)
 

soup = bs(res.content, "html.parser")
 

tag = soup.body
 

for string in tag.strings:
    stringsOut = string
    print(stringsOut)
```

my anwer so far is of type element.navigableString. I want it to be in a list of strings that contains all text from the page. Where size of the string is more than 8. Example:

```
result = ['superpowers','languages']
```

Comment: Do you mean `result = [s for s in tag.strings if len(s) > 8]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

```
tag = soup.body
my_list = list()
for string in tag.strings:
    for word in string.split(' '):
        if len(word) > 8:
            my_list.append(word)

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is where [`.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) comes into play. Because you probably want to strip whitespaces too:

```
tag = soup.body
print([i for i in tag.stripped_strings if len(i) > 8])
```